# Data pushing from Oracle to Microsoft SQL server via database link

Tags: sql-server, oracle

We have created a database link from Oracle database to MS sql server database using Oracle hetrogeneous services.
There is a table A in Oracle DB and Table B in SQL server DB. Table structures are different. I am selecting some rows from Oracle dB and pushing to mssqlserver DB via Database link using Insert statement.

The performance of this query is slow. I checked the Oracle logs. It is Saying HS agent wait event means waiting for SQL server to finish the insert and response back.

Could you please suggest performance improve methods in SQL server side. For 1000 records push it taking 24 seconds.Our Aim is to push 100000 record in 3-5 minutes. I am doing a commit on every 1000 successful inserts.

The query block used for insert is pasted below.

```
declare
v_id number:=0;
v_count number:=0;
cursor test_cur is
  select  Post_txn_balance,
      Toll_revenue_type,
      Extern_file_id,
      Card_issuer_id,
      Card_no,
      Tx_seq_number,
      Recv_extn_loc_id,
      Device_no,
      Revenue_date,
      TO_CHAR(Posted_date,'YYYY-MM-DD')Posted_date,
      Purse_ind,
      Recv_extn_sp_id,
      Lane_tx_type,
      Lane_id, 
      Lane_type, 
      Full_fare_amount,
      to_char(Tx_timestamp,'YYYY-MM-DD') Tx_timestamp
  from t_table_a
     where rownum<=10000;

test_cur_data test_cur%rowtype;

begin
      dbms_output.put_line('Going to insert 10000 records ');
      open test_cur;
    loop
     fetch test_cur into test_cur_data;
      exit when test_cur%notfound;
    v_id:=v_id+1;
        v_count:=v_count+1;
    INSERT INTO "t_table_b"@sqldb1(
          "after_card_bal",
          "app_sector",
          "batch_number",
          "card_issuer_id",
          "card_number",
          "card_status",
          "card_txn_number",
          "data_push_source",
          "debit_credit_indicator",
          "entry_loc_id",
          "entry_loc_name",
          "exit_loc_id",
          "exit_loc_name",
          "expiry_date",
          "id_number",
          "id_type",
          "mfg_number",
          "operational_date",
          "posted_date",
          "print_sp",
          "lms_process_date",
          "process_status",
          "purse_flag",
          "sp_id",
          "t_type",
          "terminal_id",
          "terminal_type",
          "txn_amount",
          "txn_date_time",
          "txn_source",
          "txn_unique_id",
          "ur_flag",
          "vector_acct_number"
          ) 
          values
          (
           test_cur_data.Post_txn_balance,
           test_cur_data.Toll_revenue_type,
           test_cur_data.Extern_file_id,
           test_cur_data.Card_issuer_id,
           test_cur_data.Card_no,
           'ACTIVE',
           test_cur_data.Tx_seq_number,
           'C',
           'D',
           '503',
           'MALYASY',
           test_cur_data.Recv_extn_loc_id,
           'MALYASY',
           '01-mar-2016',
           'ABCD123',
           'DFED12',
           test_cur_data.Device_no,
           test_cur_data.Revenue_date,
           test_cur_data.Posted_date,
           '-04',
           '01-mar-2016',
           'P',
          test_cur_data.Purse_ind,
          test_cur_data.Recv_extn_sp_id, 
          test_cur_data.Lane_tx_type, 
            test_cur_data.Lane_id, 
          test_cur_data.Lane_type, 
                    test_cur_data.Full_fare_amount,
                    test_cur_data.Tx_timestamp,
          'T',
          v_id,
          'P',
          '123456'
            );
        IF v_count=1000 then
         commit;
         v_count:=0;
        end if;
      end loop;
      commit;
    v_id:=0;
    v_count:=0;
  EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('Error while pushing data'||sqlerrm);
    ROLLBACK;
end;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want high performance in database (with or without database links), you should stop updating or inserting row by row and instead use bulk operations, i.e. SQL statements that write a lot of data at once.

So forget all the PL/SQL stuff and just run this single INSERT statement:

```
INSERT INTO "t_table_b"@sqldb1(
    "after_card_bal",
    "app_sector",
    "batch_number",
    "card_issuer_id",
    "card_number",
    "card_status",
    "card_txn_number",
    "data_push_source",
    "debit_credit_indicator",
    "entry_loc_id",
    "entry_loc_name",
    "exit_loc_id",
    "exit_loc_name",
    "expiry_date",
    "id_number",
    "id_type",
    "mfg_number",
    "operational_date",
    "posted_date",
    "print_sp",
    "lms_process_date",
    "process_status",
    "purse_flag",
    "sp_id",
    "t_type",
    "terminal_id",
    "terminal_type",
    "txn_amount",
    "txn_date_time",
    "txn_source",
    "txn_unique_id",
    "ur_flag",
    "vector_acct_number"
    )
SELECT
    Post_txn_balance,
    Toll_revenue_type,
    Extern_file_id,
    Card_issuer_id,
    Card_no,
    'ACTIVE',
    Tx_seq_number,
    'C',
    'D',
    '503',
    'MALYASY',
    Recv_extn_loc_id,
    'MALYASY',
    '01-mar-2016',
    'ABCD123',
    'DFED12',
    Device_no,
    Revenue_date,
    TO_CHAR(Posted_date,'YYYY-MM-DD'),
    '-04',
    '01-mar-2016',
    'P',
    Purse_ind,
    Recv_extn_sp_id, 
    Lane_tx_type, 
    Lane_id, 
    Lane_type, 
    Full_fare_amount,
    to_char(Tx_timestamp,'YYYY-MM-DD'),
    'T',
    v_id,
    'P',
    '123456'
from t_table_a;
```

Is shorter, simpler and faster.